# Magento 2 System configuation Group

Tags: magento2, system-configuration

I want to add one group like Screenshot in system configuration, How can i add this configuration?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 allows you to create custom fields in system configurations. There are two components needed:

Frontend model – the element renderer class responsible for the field view. This class must implement the Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Renderer\RendererInterface interface. The custom renderer class needs to be specified in the frontend_model node of the field definition in system.xml file.

Backend model – the config data model class provides the backend logic for system configuration value. In most cases, it is used for the field data preparation before saving and after loading. The configuration field backend model must implement the Magento\Framework\App\Config\ValueInterface interface.

You can use below tutorial link. It is similar to what you asked.

https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/dynamic-fields-in-system-configuration/